# Получение view во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Есть фрагмент:

```
public class CurrentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current, null);

        return view;
    }
    public void GetCurrInfo(String url){
        final WebView current_web = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_web);
    }
}
```

Но когда я хочу в методе `GetCurrInfo` подключить `WebView`, `view` горит красным. Знаю почему не работает, но не знаю как сделать правильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте `getView()` с `try/catch` NPE, либо сделайте `view` переменной класса

Comment: `getView()` работает. А обязательно использовать обработку NPE?

Comment: нет, вообще не обязательный, но чисто теоретически могут возникнуть ситуации, когда функция вызвана, а фрагмент еще не прогрузился. Блок `try/catch` поможет в таких редких случаях не вылететь всей программе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная `View view` объявлена в методе `onCreateView` и, засим, является локальной переменной этого метода. Т.е. она видна/доступна только в этом методе. В других методах её не видно, о чём компилятор вам и сообщает.

В данном случае вам можно или использовать `getView()` метод фрагмента или, что лучше, объявить `WebView currentWeb` полем класса, инициализировать её в методе `onCreateView` и в методе использовать эту переменную:

```
public class CurrentFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView currentWeb;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current, null);
        currentWeb = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_web);
        return view;
    }

    public void getCurrInfo(String url){
         currentWeb.loadUrl(url); 
    }
}
```